# iptables - how can I forward all ports (my outgoing traffic) through a local-proxy / SSH?

Tags: ssh, iptables

I have a very basic understanding of iptables from reading about 30 different similar questions people have asked and some tutorials. What I am trying to do is forward all of my outgoing traffic through SSH, to have it function as a sort of universal socks proxy. I don't have a way to test this right now, but this is what I've come up with on my own:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --destination-port 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to-port 22
```

The first rule should automatically accept anything already destined for port 22, while the second rule should redirect any remaining outgoing packets to port 22.

My main issue is that I don't have a complete understanding on the differences between PREROUTING and OUTPUT, because I've seen them both be used in different ways to forward ports like this.

Answer (score 0):

Use [tsocks](http://tsocks.sourceforge.net/)

> "Through use of the LD_PRELOAD environment variable or the
>   /etc/ld.so.preload file tsocks is automatically loaded into the
>   process space of every executed program. From there it overrides the
>   normal connect() function by providing its own. Thus when an
>   application calls connect() to establish a TCP connection it instead
>   passes control to tsocks"

Comment: there's also dante-client doing the same trick with socksify. And for the solution, don't forget to use the "ssh -D" option to create the dynamic tunnel, acting as a socks server for those commands.